# Como somar valores duplicados de um arrayList de objetos e manter apenas 1 de cada objeto duplicado?

Tags: java, array, matemática

Olá tenho o seguinte problema e estou tendo bastante dificuldade em resolvelo. Tenho um código que aplica uma formula matematica. Essa formula acaba sendo aplicada varias vezes. cada vez ela gera um objeto o nome e o resultado. O problema e que tenho que somar todos os objetos que tenham o mesmo nome em um unico resultado.

Exemplo resumido

```
class Formula(){
 private String nome;
 private String formula;
 private float resultado;
}
```

A lista tem elementos com mesmo nome e formula

```
ArrayList<Formula> resultados = new ArrayList<>();
```

Então a lista acaba tendo valores tipo assim

> resultados.get(0) = "FOMULA1","2+4","6";
>
> resultados.get(1) = "FOMULA1","2+4","6";
>
> resultados.get(2) = "FOMULA1","2+4","6";

O que eu preciso e gerar um novo ArrayList que contenha a soma total de todos os resultados com o mesmo nome. que retorne assim

> resultadosAtualizados.get(0) = "FORMULA1","2+4","18"
>
> resultadosAtualizados.get(1) = "FORMULA2","1+1","6"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu crio um novo arrayList chamado novositems, Pego o arrayList de formulas original "this.tabela.getItem" e comparo com as formulas geradas usando o nome como comparador. Depois de feito eu salvo o objeto temporario "it"
no novo arrayList "novosItems"

```
        ArrayList<Item> novosItems = new ArrayList<>();
        //Soma todos os duplicados.
        for(Item it: this.tabela.getItem()){
            float soma = 0;
            for(Item it2: listaItem){
                if(it.getNomeItem().equalsIgnoreCase(it2.getNomeItem())){
                    soma += it2.getResultado();
                    it.setResultado(soma);
                }
            }
            novosItems.add(it);
        }
```